# Login error to database for Team Foundation Server 2010

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, tfs, sql-server-express

I have installed Team Foundation Server 2010 (basic configuration) on a Windows Server 2003 without any problems. But when I go to administer the Team Foundation Server Administration Console, I get the error when in the press "Administer Security" or "Group Membership"

Server was Unable to process request. ---> Team Foundation services are not available from the server. Technical information (for administrator): The request colud note asking Processed Because the application is configured correctly note. No host service is available for the request.

If I try to go to http://localhost:8080/tfs, an I Get Runtime Error

In the Event Viewer I get following errors each time I try to do anything

- Failue Aud - MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS - Login failed for user 'SAG-S01\ASPNET'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: ]
- Error - TFS Services - Exception Message: TF246017: Team Foundation Server could not connect to the database. Verify that the server that is hosting the database is operational, and that network problems are not blocking communication with the server. (type DatabaseConnectionException)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I found where the problem was. It was set in the IIS server that TFS would run with .NET 1.1 instead of 4.0

Answer (score 1):

You could start investigating by starting the SQL Server Management Studio and navigate to the SQLExpress instance on your data tier. See if the Tfs databases are running and whether the ASPNET user has access rights for the database.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird. Can you check that you can access the database via Sql Server Management Studio.
If you can access with local system account or sa user; you have to deep dive form TFS - SQL Server connections. May be your user doesn't grant to connect SQL. Please try first, connect via Management Studio.